# Unknown amount of pictures added

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to set up a something where I can display multiple pictures but I don't know the exact amount of photos I'm going to have. I was thinking about just adding a bunch of `JLabels` to a `JPanel` but I want them to be laid out nicely. So basically what I'm asking is how can I set up this display since I don't know the exact amount of pictures I'll have until I run the program.

Comment: _"but I want them to be layed out nicely."_ - The answer to this question would be a matter of opinion, unless you state exactly what _"nice"_ means. How do you want them laid out? In a grid like pattern? Please be more descriptive of your desired result.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a JList and add the JList to a JScrollPane so that scrollbars will appear when necessary. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and examples.

You can add an ImageIcon to the JList.

Comment: @peeskillet, thanks, that's a possibility but I would consider a JLIst in this case because of the built in selection support. Guess it really depends on the OP's requirements.